# Unable to log inside TopShelf BeforeStartingService Callback

Tags: topshelf

I've written a TopShelf service and I'd like to do some validation when the service starts. If the service is horribly misconfigured, I want to give a nice error message and gracefully stop.

To do that, I've put my validation code into BeforeStartingService. When I run my service from the console, this works great. However, when I run as a service, my logging code doesn't write anything.

Is this an appropriate use case for BeforeStartingService? Is there some trick that I need to write to the log from it? I'm using Log4Net. I've tried disabling log4net entirely and just using the default trace logger. I've tried getting the logger through TopShelf with HostLogger.Get, as well as directly from Log4Net with LogManager.GetLogger.

Thanks in advance.